# Render different components when active on Navlink

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router`'s `NavLink` component to show a sidebar menu and inside the `NavLink` I have an icon. I want to change the icon so when the link is active the icon is filled. The code is somehting like this:

```
<NavLink
  to={route}
  exact
  activeClassName="selected"
>
  <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
</NavLink>
```

Is there a way to render different components inside a `NavLink` component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in your rendering function:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var isActive = this.context.router.route.location.pathname === this.props.to;

    return(
        <NavLink
          to={route}
          exact
          activeClassName="selected"
        >
         <Icon>{isActive && icon || otherIcon}</Icon>
        </NavLink>
    );
  }
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};
```

This way you are actually checking if the route you are rendering is the active one and in case choose the correct Icon

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer, can you explain where you get this: `this.context`? Is it possible to get it in functional component?

Answer (score 2):

For a more independent component that will not need to be connected in a special way to context or redux. You could use withRouter, HOC element from react-router. After wrapping you have the match, location, history available for your component. So then you can check your route / to path string to the location object.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Yes, that's a good option too, but in the project I was working this components never had the `withRouter` HOC. Thanks!